# Need someone to help you want to manage points for members to code interface functions? thank you

Tags: plugin-development

```
// hook when user logs in
add_action('wp_login', 'your_function', 10, 2);

function your_function($user_login, $user) {

    $user_id = $user->ID;
    // getting prev. saved meta
    $first_login = get_user_meta($user_id, 'points', true);
    // if first time login
    if( $first_login == '1' ) {
        // update meta after first login
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'points', '1000');
        // redirect to given URL
        wp_redirect( 'http://levangiang.net/' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone for help

Comment: what is wrong with that code? what is the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're trying to set the "points" user meta value to 1000 when the user logs in for the first time, is that correct?

I also assume that that field is empty or 0 when the user registers, and that's why your code does not work. Change

```
if( $first_login == '1' ) {
```

to

```
if( ! $first_login ) {
```

if that is the case. If it's not, please add more details to the question, it's hard to take a stab in the dark.

Comment: Can you write a user interface management point help me? I have not learned? thank you

Comment: No. But if you start learning, try it yourself, you can ask for help here, and I'm sure many people will be more than happy to point you in the right direction when you run into problems. Writing the code for you? No.